# Needing z-index property when working with float divs

Tags: javascript, css, web

I found a pair or three similar questions **but all of them are asuming it simply lacks position:absolute/relative (note for the non-readers)**. What if my requirement is using a float and then try to do a workaround for solving a z-index issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/LcwVx/1/

I have an image with a transparency. I'd like to make a floating over div to be transparent or z-index behind the parent one. I don't want to change order of calls in css neither changing position on attirbutes. Is there any way (jQuery or whatever) to solve this situation?

```
#parent {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    float:left; /* Requirement */
    border: 1px solid;
    background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ball/256/transparent.png') no-repeat top left; //ICON HAS TRANSPARENCY
}

#child {
    float:right; /* Requirement */
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: orange; 
    z-index: -1; //THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LcwVx/4/   ----opacity

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/LcwVx/5/

Comment: Nice! best answer so far. The problem is that ball gets tinted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you want to use the floats to position it. However adding a `position:relative;` to child without giving a top/left/right/bottom position you should get what you want.

The z-index property will not have any effect if there is no position set.

http://jsfiddle.net/LcwVx/6/

Comment: Maybe I am begginer but is it normal to float an element and then position it? Thought it was not compatible

Comment: Yeah shouldn't be a problem to do that.

Answer (score 4):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements, so just add `position:relative;` to your `#child` div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LcwVx/3/)**

Comment: I appreciate your help, but please, read my introduction. I simply cannot use a fixed element, so either no solution for me or another creative workaround

Comment: Where did I mention a fixed element? Simply add the rule `position:relative;` to your existing rules. No other changes needed.

Comment: Sorry I meant a non-floating element

Comment: Where is it not floating??

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, I always thought that positioned elemtns could not be floated

Comment: As you found out, that's not true. But in order for the z-index property to work, you need to set a position. In this case, relative does the job.